# What exactly can @supports test for (or not)?

Tags: css, cross-browser, feature-detection

What counts as a valid "[feature query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports)" for the purposes of @supports? I've been experimenting and so far it doesn't support (incorrectly returns false) many supported features in 2018 Chrome/FF/Safari:

```
(div:nth-child(3))
(width:max-content)
(width:minmax(auto,50%))
// ... and so on ...
```

Those seem like properly formed "[property:value pairs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports)" to me. What are the parameters for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test for selectors with @supports. It requires a statement, such as `max-width: 10em` or `color: black`. Since a function is part of a statement, such as `width: calc(100% - 12px)`, this would also be accepted.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports for more info

Comment: That would make sense, but it still doesn't work. The following @supports statements still fail: (div:nth-child(3)) (width: max-content) (width: minmax(auto, 50%))